# varnish 3.0.3 expires header

Tags: nginx, varnish-vcl

Am working with varnish-3.0.3 and my expires header is set to Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT.I want to configure it in a way the expires header is set to the days date and cache is flushed after 3600sec

Answer (score 0):

You can send **max-age** header instead of **Expires** header and will have the same effect.

Backend app should add this header on response:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
```